# Android: how to allow the navigation in a ListView on non-touchscreen devices?

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, touchscreen

I would like to get rid of the Android Market filter android.hardware.touchscreen in order to allow the download of my app on non-touchscreen devices (device with keyboard navigatio only).

There are not so much devices which are not touchscreen but there are some...

My app works with keyboard except the ListViews... I would like the user to be able to navigate in my ListView only with the keyboard. Namely, he must be able to scroll in the listView => the different cells have to be highlighted successively when he scrolls.

How to do that ?

Thanks !!

Comment: normally, any listview can be used with up/down keys. it only requires to be focused, so first check which component gets the focus, and give it to your list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create a onKeyListener. It goes something like this:

```
private class myListKeyListener implements onKeyListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

        if (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == arg2.getAction()) {
            switch (arg1) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP: {

                    int i = list.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if (i > 0)
                        i--;
                    list.setSelection(i);
                    break;}
}
```

the same thing for DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT...you can do what you want with it

After that attach listener to your list in onCreate method:

`list.setOnKeyListner(new MyListKeyListener);`

Hope it helps you ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be, you need to overide onKeyDown event and change to the focus of list view items accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer, just a sidenote**

> Android Market filter [...] non-touchscreen devices

Android devices that want to use google apps, including the Android Market must comply with the *Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)* ([see here](http://source.android.com/faqs.html#what-is-the-role-of-android-market-in-compatibility) and [here](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html)).

From this document ([current release](http://source.android.com/compatibility/2.3/android-2.3.3-cdd.pdf)):

> **7.2.4. Touchscreen input**
>
> Device implementations:
>
> • MUST have a touchscreen
>   • MAY have either capacitive or resistive touchscreen

Are you sure that there are devices that have no touchscreen *and* can access the Android Market (apart from some hacks)?

Comment: Thanks for the info concerning Google Maps. You are probably right: non touchscreen phones may not have access to the Android Market (http://www.uberphones.com/2011/01/motorola-i886-android-phone/). Thanks